# Passing data to the struct from iphdr

Tags: c, arrays, linux, sockets, struct

I'm not very experienced in C programming, but I have tried to capture and analyze packet data using C, but I have a problem that i can't pass the data to the variables inside the stuct. There are my structs:

```
struct ipOut {
    unsigned int ipVer;
    unsigned int headerDWORDS;
    unsigned int headerBytes;
    unsigned int typeOfService;
    unsigned int ipLength;
    unsigned int ident;
    unsigned int ttl;
    unsigned int protocolNum;
    unsigned int checkSum;
   };
struct ipAddr{
    char srcIP[16];
    char destIP[16];
};
struct hexOut{
    unsigned char * hexBuff;
};
struct sockaddr_in src, dest;
```

I have got working data from the socket and sent buffer to iphdr:

```
void ipHeaderOutput(unsigned char * buff, int data) {
    packetNum++;
    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*)buff;
    memset(&src, 0, sizeof(src));
    memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
    src.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->saddr;
    dest.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->daddr;

    struct ipOut ipHeader[packetNum];
    ipHeader[packetNum].ipVer = iph->version;
    ipHeader[packetNum].headerDWORDS = (unsigned int)iph->ihl;
    ipHeader[packetNum].headerBytes = (unsigned int)iph->ihl*4;
    ipHeader[packetNum].typeOfService = (unsigned int)iph->tos;
    ipHeader[packetNum].ipLength = ntohs(iph->tot_len);
    ipHeader[packetNum].ident =  ntohs(iph->id);
    ipHeader[packetNum].ttl = (unsigned int)iph->ttl;
    ipHeader[packetNum].protocolNum = (unsigned int)iph->protocol;
    ipHeader[packetNum].checkSum = ntohs(iph->check);

    struct ipAddr ipAddr[packetNum];
    strcpy(ipAddr[packetNum].srcIP, inet_ntoa(src.sin_addr));
    strcpy(ipAddr[packetNum].destIP, inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
}
```

The ipAddr struct is getting data perfectly, without any problem. However, the data doesn't pass to the ipOut struct at all.Also the same problem I have while passing data from the buffer to hexOut struct:

```
void hexDataOut(unsigned char * buff, int data){
    hexNum++;

    struct hexOut h[hexNum];
    h[hexNum].hexBuff = (unsigned char *)malloc(65536);
    memcpy(h[hexNum].hexBuff, buff, 65536);
    h[hexNum].hexBuff = buff;
}
```

Also is it the correct way to create dynamic struct tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take a closer look at these two lines:

```
struct ipOut ipHeader[packetNum];
ipHeader[packetNum].ipVer = iph->version;
```

The first defines a *local* variable `ipHeader`, which is an array of `packetNum` elements.

The second line uses the *out of bounds* index `packetNum` to access an element in the array.

First of all, why do you declare `ipHeader` as an array? Secondly, why do you define it as a *local* variable? Thirdly, going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior* which makes your whole program *ill-formed* and invalid.

Same thing later with the `ipAddr` variable.

Comment: 1. I defined it as array, because i wanted a new variable for each packet (for example ipHeader1, ipHeader2 and so on). 2. Yeap, I'm idiot, I should correct it 3. I would read about undefined behavior, thank you

Comment: @MatthewDarens If you want the arrays to survive between calls then they can not be defined as local variables. Instead either use global variables or pass them into the function as pointers. And if you don't want the arrays to be a fixed size set at compile-time you have to research dynamic [allocation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) and [reallocation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc). Lastly, remember that array-indexes are *zero* based, so an array of `N` elements have indexes from `0` to `N - 1` (inclusive).

Comment: Thanks, I would try to fix it